# How to check if the element is near the bottom of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How is the way to check if some the element is near the bottom of the screen let say 100px from the bottom? (not the bottom of page).

The thing is i wanted that when this element is clicked, an another element will shown up and will slide to top rather to down if is near the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

You can identify when an element is under 100px from the bottom of the screen with the following condition (without the need to use jQuery):

```
if (window.innerHeight - element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 100){
  // the desired place
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a button that displays when the user is almost at the bottom of your screen and when the user clicks on it, it scrolls them back to the top of the screen.

You may want to use `JavaScript` to achieve this.

Using the `jQuery` library

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var x = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (x > 250) //The 250 is the total height of div that the user scrolls to before the button displys for the user to click
        {
            $('.button').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.button').fadeOut();
        }

        $('.button').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.topmost_div').offset().top}, 'slow'); //tell the page to scroll back to the div at the top of the page.
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Hope this helps**